# Sharepoint 2010 - Visio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio

We have in SharePoint 2010, some visio web drawings (they open wit visio services) with internal hyperlinks.
In combination with windows 7 and internet explorer 11 the links won't work. If you click on these links, nothing happens.
combination: windows 8 + IE11 we doesn't experience any problems.

Any one with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

We also experienced this issue and solved it today by changing the web part settings.
You need to disable the "Pan" functionality then your hyperlinks are available again.

[image: Web part Settings]

Background: Win7+IE11 interpret your click on the drawing as a pan action and not as a click on the hyperlinks. Once you disable the pan functionality all hyperlinks are available and working again.